# How to fix a ConsumePartition in Golang Sarama

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka, sarama

I'm doing tests with Kafka and Golang

I'm using:

Docker:
https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka

Sarama:
https://github.com/Shopify/sarama

The example is very simple is a Consumer that connects to Kafka:
https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#example-Consumer

The code is this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
)

func main() {

    consumer, err := sarama.NewConsumer([]string{"localhost:9092"}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := consumer.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }()

    partitionConsumer, err := consumer.ConsumePartition("my_topic", 0, sarama.OffsetNewest)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := partitionConsumer.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }()

    // Trap SIGINT to trigger a shutdown.
    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt)

    consumed := 0
    ConsumerLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-partitionConsumer.Messages():
            log.Printf("Consumed message offset %d\n", msg.Offset)
            consumed++
        case <-signals:
            break ConsumerLoop
        }
    }

    log.Printf("Consumed: %d\n", consumed)
}
```

but when executing:
*go run main.go*

It shows me the following error:

```
panic: dial tcp: lookup fd6ee3862a45: no such host

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/vn0sgkq/go/src/github.com/hectorgool/kafka1/main.go:25 +0x3f1
exit status 2
```

The repo is here:
https://github.com/hectorgool/kafka1/blob/master/main.go#L25

Yes, I know that I am missing the producer for the messages, but the strange thing is that: **consumer.ConsumePartition**
is not working

Comment: There are some docker networking information needed here. Are you running kafka and/or your code in docker containers. It looks like your docker network is not set up properly.

Comment: kafka is inside docker, the code is outside the container, it is in the localhost.
The code does connect the container because the line: sarama.NewConsumer ([] string {"localhost: 9092"} does not create a panic, the error is generated in the second panic corresponding to: consumer.ConsumePartition